# Word Add in VSTO - How to get multiple ranges of text copied on multi-select

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am trying to store and high-light text copied by user when he opens the word file back. When he copies one paragraph, I am able to highlight (I am storing all this copied information for e.g. range values in an XML file) but when he copies content of **multiple** paragraphs using **Ctrl** Button, I am unable to get individual range values.

Could you guys help on this?

Comment: Can you share the code that copies one paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not supported by (the current versions of) Word because programmatic access to discontiguous selection is limited. In particular, you cannot access the different ranges in that selection (you can only the last subrange).

The limitations are listed in detail in this MSDN article:

> [**Limited programmatic access to Word discontiguous selections**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288424)